# How to find a post id using the post_excerpt?

Tags: wp-query, excerpt

I know how to find the post_excerpt using the post ID, but is it possible to find a post ID using an excerpt?  Every time I search for this, all that comes up is how to find the post_excerpt from the ID.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the use case for knowing the post except but not knowing the post ID?

Comment: I am using Advanced Custom Fields, I know what the except is for a "field group" that is stored as a post (it's based on the title I gave the group).  I need to provide the ID of the group when creating a form with their API.

Comment: I chose kero's answer because it supplied the code to do the search I was requesting.  But Tom J Nowell and Mark Kaplun both gave me good reasons not to try it in this manner.  Mark explained why to avoid it in detail, which helped me find a better solution.  Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the post ID from the excerpt, but as far as I can tell, `WP_Query` doesn't support this (very well), so you need to write a custom WPDB query.

```
function get_post_id_by_excerpt($excerpt) {
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_row( 
        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_excerpt LIKE %s", $excerpt) 
    );
    return $result;
}
```

For this to work, you need to pass the exact excerpt (incl. HTML) to the function

Comment: Thanks kero, you say I would need to "pass the exact excerpt (incl. HTML)" in the database, the excerpt is simply three words separated by hyphens, no HTML in it.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

**Via the APIs? No**, the excerpt is not an option in `WP_Query` which is what powers all the other functions. [See here for a full list of options](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

It will attempt this indirectly if you do a search, but this also searches the post content and title

**To do this explictly you will need to do a raw SQL query**, via `$wpdb`, and keep in mind this probably won't be a fast query, I would advise against it

Comment: Funny enough, `WP_Query` [does check for `post_excerpt` in some cases](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1477), it just does not give the option to search for/filter by it..

Comment: Thanks for the info and link to the full list.  Is $wpdb slow by it's very nature or is it because of what I am searching for?  If it's always slow, then how can the API be faster, I assume it would have to do a SQL query at some point to get the data?

Comment: @SoloCrowd wpdb is used for every DB query in WordPress, so the class itself isn't slow, it's the query you ask it that determines how fast it is or not. Searching for post IDs via excerpts won't be the slowest thing you can do, but that table isn't optimised for that kind of search. Make sure you specify the posts status in the query so it speeds things up, and set a limit manually in your query of 1 so it stops searching. If you've got queries with `meta_query` those will be much slower than this

Answer (score 0):

99% of the time it is not possible, at least not without a ridiculously slow algorithm.

The reason is  that excerpt are may both be automatically generated and/or sanitized, making the resulting excerpt to not exactly match neither the `post_content` nor `post_excerpt`.

Chances of getting it right when you are dealing with a manual excerpt are probably much higher than when dealing with automatic one, but people add them relatively rarely.

Comment: I see, so the excepts tend to hold many words, making them slow to search.  Instead I should try to narrow the posts to search with a different field first, such as post_type, which would be in my case "acf-field-group".  Then instead of searching the excepts of 1000+ posts, I would search only ~10 posts.

Comment: the main problem is the automatically generated ones. how do you know if "I am an excerpt" is manual which is relatively easy, or automattic. which might be very hard unless you actually gona generate the excerpt for each post and compare. It sound like whatever is the problem you are facing, there has to be a better solution than comparing excerpts.